# Injecting HttpContext.Current.Session in legacy code using Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

**tl;dr**:
In a legacy app, culture info is stored in `HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"]`. How do I introduce DI with Windsor here, so that when running the application still gets and sets culture info there, but I can mock it in my tests?

**Full background:**
I have some legacy code for localization, that I wish to refactor to enable mocking and testing. Currently, a custom class `Lang` fetches localized strings based on a provided `string key` and on `HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] as CultureInfo`.

My initial idea was to simply inject a `CultureInfo` instance using Windsor, and install it to get it from the same place as before when running the entire web application, but when testing I'd simply register a `new CultureInfo("en-GB")` instead. This is what I came up with for the installers:

```
public class CultureInfoFromSessionInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register( // exception here (see comments below)
            Component.For<CultureInfo>()
            .Instance(HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] as CultureInfo)
            .LifeStyle.PerWebSession());
    }
}
class EnglishCultureInfoInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<CultureInfo>()
            .Instance(new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
    }
}
```

But now when running the application I get a null reference exception on the indicated line. I suspect this is because I'm trying to hook this up too early - the container is initialized and the installer registered under `Application_Start` in Global.asax.cs, and I'm not sure `HttpContext.Current.Session` (or even `HttpContext.Current`) is set by then.

Is there a nice way to obtain what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I wonder where that ugly piece of legacy code came from ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delay the instantiation of the component:

```
container.Register( 
        Component.For<CultureInfo>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] as CultureInfo)
        .LifeStyle.PerWebSession());
```

Comment: Brilliant! I never dared hoping it would be *that* easy! =)